# Implement Stack with two queues - Leetcode

Tags: c#

That's copied details from the problem from Leetcode #225:

Implement a last-in-first-out (LIFO) stack using only two queues. The implemented stack should support all the functions of a normal stack (push, top, pop, and empty).

Implement the MyStack class:

```
    void push(int x) Pushes element x to the top of the stack.
    int pop() Removes the element on the top of the stack and returns it.
    int top() Returns the element on the top of the stack.
    boolean empty() Returns true if the stack is empty, false otherwise.
```

Notes:

You must use only standard operations of a queue, which means that only push to back, peek/pop from front, size and empty operations are valid.
Depending on your language, the queue may not be supported natively. You may simulate a queue using a list or deque (double-ended queue) as long as you use only a queue's standard operating

And that's what I've done:

```
public class MyStack {

    Queue<int> firstQ = new Queue<int>();
    Queue<int> secondQ = new Queue<int>();
    public MyStack() {
        
    }
    
    public void Push(int x) {
        firstQ.Enqueue(x);
    }
    
    public int Pop() {
        if (firstQ.Count > 0)
        {
            MakeTopAlone();
            return firstQ.Dequeue();
        }
        return 1;
        
    }
    
    public int Top() {
        if (firstQ.Count > 0)
        {
            MakeTopAlone();
            return firstQ.Peek();
        }
        return 1;
    }
    
    public bool Empty() {
        bool firstEmpty = firstQ.Count() == 0;
        bool secondEmpty = secondQ.Count() == 0;
        return firstEmpty && secondEmpty;
    }

    public void MakeTopAlone(){
        int length = firstQ.Count;

        for (int i = length; i > 1; i--)
        {
            secondQ.Enqueue(firstQ.Dequeue());
        }
    }
}
```

```
The input is: 
["MyStack","push","push","top","pop","pop","empty"]
[[],[1],[2],[],[],[],[]]

The expected output is:
[null,null,null,2,2,1,true]

But i get:
[null,null,null,2,2,1,false]
```

I believe something wrong with my MakeTopAlone method wrong but i can't see what. I also don't understand if input is two pops in the row, how is second pop working if we dequeueing firstQ?

Comment: Stack overflow kept considering the implement stack class paragraph a piece of code, so i've put it in code box

Comment: Best way of learning is to debug your self.  I would add debug statements to code and output to a file where you can see what is happening.  It is easier to analyze problems like this with debug data in a file than trying to debug one instruction at a time.

Comment: Notice how you only _enqueue_ into `secondQ` ? So your implementation only works for that exact sequence of push, top, pop. But when it comes to empty, it is of course not empty. Because `secondQ` never gets _dequeued_ from.

Comment: Hint: The problem, why it _seems_ to "work" up until the "empty" call is `return 1;`. If you returned for example -1 on Popping an empty stack, you'd immidiatly see, that your implementation is not working as intended.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you never clear the second queue, so every operation leads to it being filled with all elements except the first/last one. Can copy everything back to the original one:

```
public void MakeBack()
{
    while (secondQ.TryDequeue(out var i))
    {
        firstQ.Enqueue(i);
    }
}
```

And `Pop` will look like:

```
public int Pop()
{
    MakeTopAlone();
    var result = firstQ.Dequeue();
    MakeBack();
    return result;
}
```

As for the `Top` will become something like:

```
public int Top()
{
    var result = Pop();
    firstQ.Enqueue(result);
    return result;
}
```

Also you can maintain "last" property as separate field (and change it on push/pop) so `Top` is `O(1)`.

P.S.

Also no need to count all elements in the queue, though it still should be `O(1)` in this case due to internal optimization. I would argue that `Any` is clearer approach:

```
public bool Empty() 
{
    bool firstEmpty = !firstQ.Any();
    bool secondEmpty = !secondQ.Any();
    return firstEmpty && secondEmpty;
}
```

Comment: Would Leet actually detect, that the program returns the expected results but still isn't anything but broken? I mean, technically you could pogram a complete mock that just parrots the expected output...

Comment: @Fildor yes and no. AFAIK at least some test cases operate on at least partly randomized inputs and outputs. But some can be rigged. At least previously.

Comment: In that case just clearing secondQ _shouldn't_ do the job (alone). Does it?

Comment: @Fildor yep, agree.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the following sequence:

1. `Push 2` - `2` is added to first firstQ
2. `Push 3` - `3` is added to first firstQ
3. `Pop` - `2` is transferred to secondQ, `3` is dequeued and returned
4. `Pop` - firstQ is now empty, so 1 is returned, clearly a bug.

There are several ways to fix this. One way would be to make the `Pop`-method switch the queues around after it has popped the value. So that secondQ becomes firstQ and vice versa. That way firstQ would contain the `3` when step 4 in the example is reached. So whenever a method returns, firstQ should contain all items, and secondQ should be empty.

Top Could be implemented by calling Pop, followed by a push, and then return the value.